# I want gird lines of x-axis and y-axis in highcharts but i don't want x-axis value and y-axis value

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

https://jsfiddle.net/Kondaldurgam/7kLkh7ya/8/

i want show gridines only x and y axis but but i don't have any data of x and y axis its possible to showing without data

```
$(function() {
Highcharts.chart('container', {

    chart: {
        type: 'bubble',
        plotBorderWidth: 1,
        zoomType: 'xyz'
    },
    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },
    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },

    title: {
        text: 'Using X Y Z Coordinates'
    },

    xAxis: {
        type: "category",
        gridLineWidth: 1
    },
    yAxis: {
        startOnTick: false,
        endOnTick: true,

        title: {
            text: ''
        },
    },
 });
});
```

Comment: you means you don't want to show box?

Comment: you can check in jquery data is empty or not  based on this you can visible and show your high chart div...

Comment: I want box and with grid lines but don't want x and y values

Comment: can you create one fiddler with all  data i will try..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be this will help you.. use this logic in it..[fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/gzJRN/124/)

```
$(function () {
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
          ignoreHiddenSeries : false
        },

        xAxis: {
        },

        series: [{
            data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]        
        }, {
            data: [129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4, 29.9, 71.5, 106.4]        
        }]
    });

    // the button action
  var series = chart.series[0];    
  series.hide();
  series = chart.series[1];    
  series.hide();
});
```

Comment: i don't want values

Answer (score 1):

If you have no data, you need to set `axis.showEmpty` to true and set axis min/max. You also need at least one series - it might be without data.

```
    Highcharts.chart('container', {

    chart: {
        type: 'bubble',
        plotBorderWidth: 1,
        zoomType: 'xyz'
    },
    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },
    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },

    title: {
        text: 'Using X Y Z Coordinates'
    },

    xAxis: {
        type: "category",
        gridLineWidth: 1,
        showEmpty: true,
        min: 0,
        max: 10
    },
    yAxis: {
        startOnTick: false,
        endOnTick: true,
                    showEmpty: true,
        title: {
            text: ''
        },
        min: 0,
        max: 10
    },


    series: [{}]

});
```

example: https://jsfiddle.net/7kLkh7ya/9/

Comment: i don't want min and max values i want only grid lines

Comment: You need to specify min and max values. But you can also hide the labels https://jsfiddle.net/7kLkh7ya/10/